# Cannot start indexing with solr in hybris 5.6

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I tried to do indexing via HMC but it all get aborted with below error.

```
ERROR [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] [CoreContainer] Failed to load file /hybris_extensions/hybris/config/solr/embedded/collection1/solrconfig.xml
ERROR [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] [CoreContainer] Unable to create core: collection1
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config file /hybris_extensions/hybris/config/solr/embedded/collection1/solrconfig.xml
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:530)
```

I have started solr from hybris 5.6 in standalone mode and using linux machine.

Comment: Are you using embedded or standalone SOLR server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hybris can run solr in standalone or embedded mode. When running in embedded mode, the configuration for SolR is created in the directory:

hybris/config/solr/embedded/

Therefore your hybris server needs the rights to write to this directory.

Further reading: 
https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/SolrFacetSearch+-+Installation+Guide

Comment: I have started solr in standalone mode (hybris/bin/ext-commerce/solrfacetsearch/resources/solr/server) and changed permission of all folders and files to anyone can read and write. But Still I am facing same error. I am using linux machine.

Comment: Embedded solr is for development environments. Standalone is more or less only for productional use.